# javascript and php element does'nt work

Tags: javascript, php

I want include a php element inside my script.  Do you have an idea, is it possible ?

`fileFieldImageCkeditor` call CkEditor

Tk

```
//   html += '<input type="file" name="option_value[' + option_value_row + '][image]" value="" accept="image/*" class="form-control" />';
    html += <?php echo $this->fileFieldImageCkeditor('option_value[\' + option_value_row + \'][image]', null, '125', '75'); ?>
```

my function :

```
public static function fileFieldImageCkEditor($name, $value = null, $width = null, $height = null) {
  if (is_null($height)) {
   $height = '250';
  }

  if (is_null($width)) {
    $width = '250';
  }

  $field = '<textarea name="' . HTML::output($name) . '" /></textarea>';
  $field .= '<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace(\'' . HTML::output($name) . '\',
  {
    width : '. $width .',
    height : ' . $height . ',
    filebrowserBrowseUrl :"' . OSCOM::link('Shop/ext/elFinder-master/elfinder-cke.html') . '",
 });
        </script>';
  return $field;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing anything else, since you provided very little... I would say wrap that <php> tag insert with single or double quotes and hope for the best.

Comment: @IncredibleHat; Tk. I tried "<?php ... ?>", does'n work. I inserted the function above

Comment: Yeah, I see. Your function outputs mixed single and double quotes, so just dropping it inside of either, is going to result in invalid javascript. Sadly, you will have to do some quote-wrangling to get this to work right.

Comment: @IncredibleHat What do mean exactly ! quote-wrangling. Do you have an example ? It will be base to try !

Answer (score -1):

**It should work. Just be ready to debug in case you mismatch the single vs double quotes**
You need to closely inspect your code so this would work properly. Your second line don't have enclosing quotes, why?
Also if semicolon becomes a problem (very unlikely) use PHP_EOPL instead.